# Combinations of size n from multiset

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a multiset as shown below

{0.5, 0.5, 1, 1}

I want to get the combinations of size n like:

0.5, 0.5

1, 1

1, 0.5

(Note the combinations of coins are unique. So 0.5, 1 is same as 1, 0.5.)

How do I calculate the number of combinations? I am pretty new to combinatorics, so an easy to understand algorithm would be helpful.

Comment: It's not a combinatorics question yet.  You have to figure out what the conditions are before you can count the ways to satisfy them.  When will the sums be the same?

Comment: I think it is a combinatorics question. I should have said how do get different combinations with a unique set of coins. The fact that their sums are also different is inconsequential.

Comment: In that case, you ought to edit the question.  I don't follow what you want though.  It's not possible for $n$ to be greater than 4, is it?